# GUI with pyqtgraph never refresh

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, beagleboneblack, pyqtgraph

I have been working on a GUI  for the beagle bone black that launch a thread when a button is clicked and starts to get data through the SPI.

This function is inside a class called Scanner(QObject) and runs in a different thread when the Start button is clicked.

```
def scan (self):
    thread_name = QThread.currentThread().objectName()
    self.sig_msg.emit('Scanning '+thread_name)
    for step in range(nsamples):
        data = self.read_reg(reg[thread_name])
        self.sig_data.emit(step, data)
        QThread.currentThread().msleep(50)
        app.processEvents() 
        if self.__abort:
            self.sig_msg.emit('scan stopped by user')
            break
    self.sig_done.emit(thread_name)
```

sig_msg is a pyqtsignal connected to the following function inside the GUI thread.

```
@pyqtSlot(int, int)
def on_scaner_data(self, t: int, y: int):
    app.processEvents()
    self.debugBox.insertPlainText('t: '+str(t)+'y: '+str(y)+'\n')
    self.debugBox.ensureCursorVisible()
    self.MainGraph.update_fig(t,y)
```

And finally the MainGraph.update_fig() is called. Inside that function i have used setData(self.datat,self.datay) and app.processEvents() for update the graph, but nothing changes. If i run plot(self.datat,self.datay) instead it redraws the graph but causes a huge performance hit.

```
class DynamicPlotter(PlotWidget):
def __init__(self,parent=None):
    PlotWidget.__init__(self)
    self.setParent(parent)
    # Use getPlotItem() to get the PlotItem inside PlotWidget. 
    self.pitem = self.getPlotItem()
    #now pitem is our PlotItem
    self.pitem.curve=self.pitem.plot()
    #curve is a new PlotDataItem added by PlotItem.plot()
    self.datat = [1,2]
    self.datay = [1,2] 
    self.pitem.curve.setData(self.datat,self.datay)
    #this graph works fine
    self.datat = []
    self.datay = []        
def update_fig(self,t:int,y:int):    
    self.datat.append(t)
    self.datay.append(y)
    #it works
    self.pitem.curve=self.pitem.plot(self.datat,self.datay)
    #it doesn't
    self.pitem.curve.setData(self.datat,self.datay)
    app.processEvents()
    print (self.datat)
    log.debug(str(t)+str(y))
def reset_figure(self):
    log.debug('clean graph')
    self.clear()
```

I have been following this example from the pyqtplot and my idea was do something similar inside my GUI.

```
   import initExample
   from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
   import numpy as np
   import pyqtgraph as pg
   from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
   app = QtGui.QApplication([])
   p = pg.plot()
   p.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: PlotSpeedTest')
   p.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, -10, 5000, 20)) 
   p.setLabel('bottom', 'Index', units='B')
   curve = p.plot()
   data = np.random.normal(size=(50,5000))
   ptr = 0
   lastTime = time()
   fps = None
   def update():
       global curve, data, ptr, p, lastTime, fps
       curve.setData(data[ptr%10])
       ptr += 1
       now = time()
       dt = now - lastTime
       lastTime = now
       if fps is None:
           fps = 1.0/dt
       else:
           s = np.clip(dt*3., 0, 1)
           fps = fps * (1-s) + (1.0/dt) * s
       p.setTitle('%0.2f fps' % fps)
       app.processEvents()  ## force complete redraw
   timer = QtCore.QTimer()
   timer.timeout.connect(update)
   timer.start(0)
```

I have been reading the documentation and right know I'm not sure where is/are the problems. I bet for the threads or the event loop handler but i don't know. 
Which are the critical points that i have to review?
Any clue?

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend that you add the `pyqtgraph` tag to your post. I'd do it myself but you have to remove another tag (you can have max. 5 tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while i have found the problem by myself.
I fixed the problem changing the way that i was using to reset the graph and stopping the scan thread until elements are plot.

Changes on reset function. self.clear() remove the traces on the PlotWidget and that wasn't what i needed.

```
 def reset_figure(self):
    log.debug('clean graph')
    self.datat =[]
    self.datay=[]
    self.pitem.curve.setData(self.datat,self.datay)
```

Scan was modified to stop while the data is plotted in the other thread. sync_to_plot stop the thread execution until self._wait=False. This value is changed by wait_state.

```
def scan (self):
    thread_name = QThread.currentThread().objectName()
    #thread_id = str(QThread.currentThreadId())#review
    self.sig_msg.emit('Scanning '+thread_name)
    for step in range(nsamples):
        data = self.read_reg(reg[thread_name])
        self.sig_data.emit(step, data)
        #pause while plot values
        self.sync_to_plot()
        if step % refrate == 0:
            log.debug("%5d : %d" % (step, data) )
        if self.__abort:
            self.sig_msg.emit('scan stoped by user')
            break
    self.sig_done.emit(thread_name)

def sync_to_plot(self):
    self._wait=True
    while self._wait:
        log.debug("waiting")
        QThread.currentThread().msleep(1)
        app.processEvents()
 def wait_state(self, stat):
    self._wait=stat
```

With that done the last change was on the on_scaner_data that unblocks the thread that is waiting on sync_to_plot.

```
@pyqtSlot(int, int)
def on_scaner_data(self, t: int, y: int):
    app.processEvents()
    self.debugBox.insertPlainText('t: '+str(t)+'y: '+str(y)+'\n')
    self.debugBox.ensureCursorVisible()
    self.MainGraph.update_fig(t,y)
    for thread, scaner in self.__threads:
        scaner.wait_state(False)
        log.debug("scanner false")
```